# Can't find MapKit framework in link binary with libraries

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am new in iOS developing. I am building a basic map view project. Now in "Build Phases" and in  "Link binary with libraries" I can't find the "MapKit" framework which I have to add. Can any one solve my problem please? Thanks in advance. My Xcode version is 6.0.1 and as I am a beginner and I don't have 10 reputations so I can't upload screenshot.

Comment: What happens if you go to the project settings, go to the Capabilities tab, and switch Maps to ON?

Comment: when I am switching on the Maps an issue is coming in steps. When I am clicking on fix issue it is showing that "The framework 'MapKit.framework' was not found in the SDK for this target. @Anna

Answer (score 0):

i think you might have deleted the framework accidentally, you can download and install the framework for here,https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74641080/MapKit.framework.zip